# Categorial Terminal Object for Java

Tags: java, functional-programming, category-theory

I am looking for a canonical representation in Java of a categorical terminal object (**1**); an object that can only take one value.

I am aware that `Void` is available. However, this is more appropriately the initial object (**0**) because it cannot be instantiated. I am aware I could return a `null` `Void` object. In this sense, every Java object is **+1**. I want to write `null` free code for this very reason. Furthermore, returning `null` is not a workable solution for my particular use-case.

Comment: `enum One { ONE; }`

Answer (score 1):

Let's at least restate the definitions briefly,
and separate the interfaces from the implementation. First, the interface:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

interface TerminalObj<X> {
  <Y> Function<Y, X> uniqueTerminalMorphism();
}
```

Now, unsurprisingly, an enum with a single element as terminal object:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

enum Unit {
  UNIT;

  public static TerminalObj<Unit> terminalObj() {
    return new TerminalObj<Unit>() {
      public <X> Function<X, Unit> uniqueTerminalMorphism() {
        return x -> UNIT;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

A really boring demo:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

class TerminalObjMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TerminalObj<Unit> universalProperty = Unit.terminalObj();
    Function<String, Unit> boringFunction = universalProperty.<String>uniqueTerminalMorphism();

    System.out.println(boringFunction.apply("Hello, world..."));
    // prints "UNIT", who would have thought that?

  }
}
```

Don't try too hard to extend this in any direction: Java doesn't even have *pairs*...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I'm not sure I understand what you mean: the `<X> uniqueTerminalMorphism` method in `TerminalObj` is *generic in `X`*. If I replace the entire `new TerminalObj`-thing by just `() -> x -> UNIT`, I get `error: incompatible types: invalid functional descriptor for lambda expression
    return () -> x -> UNIT;
           ^
    method <Y>()Function<Y,Unit> in interface TerminalObj is generic`. If this worked, then it would mean that Java had inline syntax for higher-order constructs like Natural transformations? All the Scalaz-people would switch to Java tomorrow! ;D

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I mean, even in Scala, you have to jump through burning hoops to get something similar. For example, just to write down natural transformations inline, you need something like [this compiler plugin](https://github.com/non/kind-projector#polymorphic-lambda-values). Given that Java is somewhat more conservative than crazy category-theory inspired Scala compiler plugins, I'd suspect that you can't write it down in java without a `new`. That would be just too good. Java already is making good progress, so I'm just happy about what already works ;)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner However, if you are interested in cutting-edge Java, maybe one could hack up a [`javac-compiler-plugin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javac-compiler-plugin) for exactly that? ;) That would certainly be a lot of fun.

Comment: Hey Andrey, I'm not *that* interested :D But, yes, you're right, lambdas in Java cannot target a generic single abstract method. Generic type parameters can be specified at the type level, though, but this is not the idea here ;) You can use a generic helper method, though, and then use a method reference, i.e. `public static TerminalObj<Unit> terminalObj() { return Unit::terminal; }` And the `terminal` helper generic method would be: `private static <Y> Function<Y, Unit> terminal() { return y -> UNIT; }`

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner that would only make the method available as `static`, but the `<Y>` is still there, you just can't get rid of it, the generic argument has to go *somewhere* :)

Comment: Well, you can turn it to `public static TerminalObj<Unit> terminalObj() { return UNIT::terminal; }` and the `terminal` helper method would now become a non-static method: `private <Y> Function<Y, Unit> terminal() { return y -> this; }` But this is the best you can do in Java so far. Nonetheless, there's no need for an anonymous inner class. We're fine with a new method, just because of the `Y` generic type parameter...